# regex with bs4 is splitting the results

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

My regex is producing split results so I have to subscript for a quick fix.

Code

```
my_url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine'

house_listings = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"listing-results-right clearfix"})

listings = house_listings[3] # item 3 for prototyping

house_type = re.findall('(?:(?!.for).)*', str(listings.h2.a.text))

print(house_type)
# `['4 bed detached house', '', 'for sale', '']`
```

Fix

```
house_type = re.findall('(?:(?!.for).)*', str(listings.h2.a.text))[0]
print(house_type)
# 4 bed detached house
```

But beyond that, I need a new regex for better matching.

**Desired Match**
start from the word after 'bed' (minus the following space) and ignore the "for sale" portion.
e.g. results: `detached house`, `terrace house`, `semi-detached house`, `flat`, `maisonette`.

**Source**
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
(?<=bed ).*(?= for)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kkSUft/1/)

Comment: Thanks. It's sexy. Is it not more efficient to ignore the phrase "for sale" all together? Apples and oranges? p.s. why was it splitting?

Comment: p.s. What if I wanted everything up to but not including "for sale"? If you could add that in your answer as another option that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by “ignore” for sale? You mean keep your existing solution? You certainly could. Yours is splitting because it means “take any combination of characters not followed by any character (`.`) plus the word ‘for.’” So it gives you two matches: one for everything up to “ for” and one for everything from “for” onward, since “for sale” is not followed by “for.” If you want to include “4 bed” etc just use `re.findall(r"^.*(?= for)", re.MULTILINE)`